# Programming text user interfaces on modern Windows

Tags: windows, terminal, curses

Is there any *Windows way* to go about creating text user interfaces via a terminal control library on modern Windows operating systems ? (7/8/10 etc) I am aware of the curses family of libraries have been ported from their Unix-like systems to work on Windows. But outside of that I can't find anything. Does Windows just assume you are either going to make a program handled by simple input / output to command prompt or make a full blown GUI application?

Comment: In Windows 10 the console supports [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Otherwise you have the console API, which dates back to NT 3.1 (1993). The console API is what curses libraries such as PDCurses use on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can program this sort of functionality using the Windows console API. Which is as simple as `#include <windows.h>` and making the appropriate API calls. The documentation for the console API is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

You don't actually need an additional library on top of this to be able to easily program interactive console programs.